# Formatting HTML titles in R

Tags: r

I created a table with the package reactable but I'am not sure how to format the HTML titles so they share the same style with the table, like font, colour and background color. I would like it to look like a whole thing, not like they does not fit.

This is my code:

```
library(reactable)
library(htmltools)

options(reactable.theme = reactableTheme(
  color = "hsl(233, 9%, 87%)",
  backgroundColor = rgb(38/255,42/255,51/255,142/240),
  borderColor = rgb(152/255,156/255,165/255,240/240)
  ))

example<- reactable(data.frame(country=c("argentina","brazil"),
                           value=c(1,2)
))

final <- htmlwidgets::prependContent(example, 
                                      list(h2(class = "title", "title 1"),
                                           h4(class = "subtitle", "subtitle")))


print(final)
```

What would you do?

Answer (score 2):

using the `htmltools::tags$style` creates a style tag, you can then write the css you want to be applied to the title

```r
htmlwidgets::prependContent(
    final,
    htmltools::tags$style(
      "h2, h4 {color:hsl(233, 9%, 87%)"
    )
  )
```